# Поиск пользователей, у которых скоро День Рождения

Tags: php, mysql

Вопрос такой:
В базе хранится список пользователей. Дата рождения хранится меткой юникс (может имеет смысл хранить иначе? как?).
Необходимо выводить пользователей, у которых в ближайшие дни (5 дней, например) будет День Рождения, учитывая конец месяца и года.
Как лучше организовать данную операцию?

Сделал так:

```
$drs = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_all` WHERE bir_date!=0");
while ($dr = mysql_fetch_array($drs)){
    $datet1 = strtotime(date("d.m.", $dr[bir_date]).date("Y"));
    if ($datet1>=strtotime("today") && $datet1<strtotime("+5 day")){
        echo date("d.m.Y", $dr[bir_date]);
    }                       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дата рождения хранится меткой юникс// Ага. DateTime или любой другой подобной фигней. Как показал эксперимент, скорость работы почти такая же, а восприятие человеком существенно лучше.

учитывая конец месяца и года// Не очень понятно как их учитывать. Вычитаете из вашей юникс-даты

```
N*24*60*60, где N=5 для вашего условия
```

и ищете у кого попал в этот промежуток день рождения.

Comment: "Вычитаете из вашей юникс-даты" - из которой? Из актуального времени (сегодняшнего)? Я получу промежуток - последние (прошедшие) 5 дней.
Вычитать из даты рождения? Смысл вычитать из 10.12.1988 5 дней?
В общем, я немного не понял Вашего ответа.

Comment: @M03G - надо откинуть года, т.е. что бы сравнивать все дни рождения в формате одного (1970-го) года.

Comment: Вычитаете из 10.12.%YEAR%, где %YEAR% - текущий год.   
MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_birthday)) as month,  
DAY(FROM_UNIXTIME(date_birthday)) as day,  
year(NOW()) as year,

Comment: ua6xh, откинуть низя. Потому что будут навороты с 29 февраля